# Interact with object values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
a = [{name: James, Location: London},
{name: Martin, Location: Seattle},...
{name: George, Location: New York}];
```

How can I switch the keys with its values?

Comment: Can you ask one question at a time please, and set it out so it's clear they're different questions?

Comment: Why don't you just try something yourself??? Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*First of all, you should first try yourself to find the solution of a problem. If you face any issue then you should ask the community for help. I believe in this way you can develop your skill a lot.*

The property *length* will give you the total count of items in the array. You can you can use `map()` to modify an existing array and `splice()` to insert item to a position you want.

```js
var a = [{name: 'James', Location: 'London'},
{name: 'Martin', Location: 'Seattle'},
{name: 'George', Location: 'New York'}];

// Get number of items
console.log(a.length);

// Modify items
var replaceName = a.map(p =>{
  if(p.name=='George')
    p.name = 'Suarez';
  return p;
});
console.log(replaceName);

// Add new object
var obj = {name: 'Jhon', Location: 'California'};
a.splice(1, 0, obj);
console.log(a)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am actually not able to find a place where I can get this information. Maybe I am not searching the exact keyword. Anyways thank you for this help. Means a lot.